# How to use context path to hit soap webservice?

Tags: web-services, soap, contextpath

I have changed the the context path in property file and after that when I am trying to hit webservice from SOAPUI, I am getting blank page as a response.So, I have given the same value as in context-root of jboss-web.xml. Still, facing the same issue.

```
server.contextPath=/myvalue

<context-root>/myvalue</context-root>
```

I have made some changes in SOAPWSConfig class also.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet,"/myvalue/*");
}
```

Below is the change I made in my camel route to point the URL:

```
from("spring-ws:uri:http://{{webservice.ipaddress}}:{{webservice.port}}/{{server.contextPath}}/CCSWebServiceBean/GetScheduleDetailsCCS?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")    
.unmarshal(jaxb).process(ccsServiceProcessor).marshal(jaxb);
}
```

It was working with a default contextPath value.The URL which I am using to hit from SOAPUI is:

```
http://10.80.11.65:8080/myvalue/CCSWebServiceBean/GetScheduleDetailsCCS
```

Please help to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To handle endpoint header/property dependence, you should use "[recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)".
In blueprint, it would be something like:

```
<recipientList><simple>spring-ws:uri:http://{{webservice.ipaddress}}:{{webservice.port}}/{{server.contextPath}}/CCSWebServiceBean/GetScheduleDetailsCCS?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping</simple></recipientList>
```

Same apply for plain java camel routes.